# Filtering dropdown based on another dropdown selection Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have 2 separate dropdown lists and submit button which takes the visitor to a unique URL based on selections.

I need to get each dropdown to filter each other.

for example: When someone chooses "Volvo" from the first dropdown menu, then the second drop-down menu shows only "Red" & "White" and so on.

HTML

```
<form>
  <select class="homepage-dropdown col-md-6 col-9" id="carbrand">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab" selected="selected">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
<br>
  <select class="homepage-dropdown col-md-6 col-9" id="carcolor">
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black" selected="selected">Black</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>

  <br/><br/>

  <input id="btnCallURL" type="button" value="بحث">  
</form>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('btnCallURL').onclick = function() { 
    var carbrandObj = document.getElementById('carbrand');
    var carcolorObj = document.getElementById('carcolor');

    var carbrandValue = carbrandObj.options[carbrandObj.selectedIndex].value;
    var carColorValue = carcolorObj.options[carcolorObj.selectedIndex].value;

    jsCallUrl(carbrandValue, carColorValue);
}

function jsCallUrl(carbrandValue, carColorValue){

    var pageUrl = "";

    switch (carbrandValue){
        case "volvo":
            switch (carColorValue){
            case "white":
                pageUrl = "volvo-white-page-url.php";
                break;
            case "black":
                pageUrl = "volvo-black-page-url.php";
                break;
         case "red":
                pageUrl = "volvo-red-page-url.php";
                break;
         case "blue":
                pageUrl = "volvo-blue-page-url.php";
            break;            
          }
          break;
        case "saab":
            switch (carColorValue){
            case "white":
                pageUrl = "saab-white-page-url.php";
                break;
            case "black":
                pageUrl = "saab-black-page-url.php";
                break;
            default:
                pageUrl = "saab-othercolor-page-url.php";
                break;
          }
          break;
    }



    if (pageUrl != ""){
      location.href = "https://domain/" + pageUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you comfortable with a jquery solution.

Comment: Please update it if you see that it can be written better. because I'm new in this

Comment: check the new solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** the problem of repeating values is sorted.
I've made a few changes to your HTML

```
    //new
window.addEventListener( "pageshow", function ( event ) {
          var historyTraversal = event.persisted || ( typeof window.performance != "undefined" && window.performance.navigation.type === 2 );
          if ( historyTraversal ) {
            window.location.reload();
          }
        });
<form>
  <select  onChange="populate('carbrand','carcolor');" class="homepage-dropdown col-md-6 col-9" id="carbrand">
     <option selected>select</option> 
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
<br>
  <select class="homepage-dropdown col-md-6 col-9" id="carcolor">
    <option id="select" selected>Select color</option>
  </select>
  <br/><br/>
  <input id="btnCallURL" type="button" value="بحث">  
</form>
```

And I've used **Populate** method to enter the values dynamically using Javascript.

```
<script>
function populate(s1,s2){
            var s = document.getElementById(s1);
            var s_a = document.getElementById(s2);


    var select = document.getElementById(s2).options.length;
    for (var i = select; i >0;i-- ) {
        document.getElementById(s2).options.remove(i);
        console.log(i);
    }
     document.getElementById('select').selected='selected';
  var optionArray=[];
            if(s.value == "volvo"){
                 optionArray = ["red|Red","white|White"];
            } 
      else if(s.value == "saab"){
      optionArray = ["white|White","gray|Gray"];
      }
      else if(s.value == "audi"){
       optionArray = ["black|Black","red|REd"];
      }
      else if(s.value == "opel"){
      optionArray = ["red|REd","black|Black"];
      }
            for(var option in optionArray){
                var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
                var newOption = document.createElement("option");
                newOption.value = pair[0];
                newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
                s_a.options.add(newOption);
            }
        }
document.getElementById('btnCallURL').onclick = function() { 
    var carbrandObj = document.getElementById('carbrand');
    var carcolorObj = document.getElementById('carcolor');

    var carbrandValue = carbrandObj.options[carbrandObj.selectedIndex].value;
    var carColorValue = carcolorObj.options[carcolorObj.selectedIndex].value;

    jsCallUrl(carbrandValue, carColorValue);
}

function jsCallUrl(carbrandValue, carColorValue){

    var pageUrl = "";

    switch (carbrandValue){
        case "volvo":
            switch (carColorValue){
            case "white":
                pageUrl = "volvo-white-page-url.php";
                break;
            case "black":
                pageUrl = "volvo-black-page-url.php";
                break;
         case "red":
                pageUrl = "volvo-red-page-url.php";
                break;
         case "blue":
                pageUrl = "volvo-blue-page-url.php";
            break;            
          }
          break;
        case "saab":
            switch (carColorValue){
            case "white":
                pageUrl = "saab-white-page-url.php";
                break;
            case "black":
                pageUrl = "saab-black-page-url.php";
                break;
            default:
                pageUrl = "saab-othercolor-page-url.php";
                break;
          }
          break;
    }



    if (pageUrl != ""){
      location.href = "https://domain/" + pageUrl;
    }
}
    </script>
```

Comment: great, the repeating problem has been sorted, but the button is not working.

Comment: check now, it was because the value to option was not completely in lower case

Comment: great now it's working fine. Only last note that when the button clicked and the visitor go to another page, then click the "back" button the form is not working properly. do you have a fix for this?